# Will I have the opportunity to 100% Metroid Dread before the final boss if I missed things?

Tags: metroid-dread

I'm playing Metroid Dread for 20+ hours and I'm still not done. I'm currently at the Chozo Soldier boss fight in Artaria. Currently, it seems that the game makes me face boss after boss and I don't explore much anymore. For instance, I don't seem able to come back to previous places.

I've seen screenshots of people at the same location where I currently am with way more energy and missiles than I have and the completionist in me tells me that I skipped a lot of the items.

So I'm asking myself will I have the opportunity to fully explore the planet and 100% the game before the final boss, or is it too late for me to get some items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, nothing in the game is missable, at least until you defeat the final boss.

If you're fighting the Chozo Soldier in Artaria, that means ZDR is currently frozen. At this point, you won't be able to explore the map much, because almost every door will be frozen shut.

Once you defeat the next boss in Cataris, ZDR should return to normal, and you'll be able to explore freely once more.

However, you might not be able to fully explore ZDR until you acquire the Screw Attack<sup>*****</sup>, and you'll also need the Power Bombs if you're aiming for 100% completion. In fact, the Power Bombs are acquired not long before you need to face the final boss. Therefore, you'll need to do some extensive backtracking if you're aiming for 100% completion.

---

<sup>*****</sup>: If you're sequence breaking, it's possible you haven't acquired the Space Jump yet. You'll need that as well, if you want to reach every nook and cranny of ZDR.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in Dread is missable. The game likes to stop you from backtracking to help prevent you from getting too lost, but these blockades will all be circumventable as you get power-ups. You won't be able to get 100% until you're basically at the final boss's door anyway, so might as well wait until you get into the final area and reach the final elevator, since at that point all the Teleportals become interconnected and backtracking will be much easier.